# Search with LIKE in PostgreSQL array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, comparison-operators

I have this table:

```
 id |   name   |          tags           
----+----------+-------------------------
  1 | test.jpg | {sometags,other_things}
```

I need to get rows that contain specific tags by searching in array with regular expression or `LIKE`, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE 'some%' LIKE any(tags);
```

But this query returns nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with images (id, name, tags) as (values
    (1, 'test.jpg', '{sometags, other_things}'::text[]),
    (2, 'test2.jpg', '{othertags, other_things}'::text[])
)
select *
from images
where (
    select bool_or(tag like 'some%')
    from unnest(tags) t (tag)
);
 id |   name   |          tags           
----+----------+-------------------------
  1 | test.jpg | {sometags,other_things}
```

[`unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) returns a set which you aggregate with the convenient [`bool_or`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) function